# Is ProcessorCount is sensible value for maxCount in SemaphoreSlim?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, semaphore

In code of my colleagues I've noticed code like this:

```
private Task FetchAllKeysFromRedis(List<string> keys, ConcurrentBag<RedisModel> resultsBag, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
        var parallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        var semafore = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: parallelism, maxCount: parallelism);
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            tasks.Add(FetchFromRedis(key, semafore, resultsBag, cancellationToken));
        }

        return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

`List<string> keys` approximately contains around 1000 keys, and `FetchFromRedis` method asynchronously execute I/O operaion (fetch from Redis), so to sum up it executes around 1000 of I/O operations.

Critical section look like this:

```
private async Task FetchFromRedis(string key, SemaphoreSlim semafore, ConcurrentBag<RedisResult> resultsBag, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     await semafore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
     try
     {
         var redisResult = await _getRedisResultFromRedis.ExecuteAsync(key, cancellationToken);
         if (redisResult != null)
              resultsBag.Add(redisResult);
      
         finally
         {
            semafore.Release();
         }
      }
```

My question: is `Environment.ProcessorCount` sensible `maxCount` for `SemaphoreSlim`? As it will limit count of threads that can step into critical section to very low, like 8, and time of execution will be much longer?

If it not sensible, then what is sensible value for `maxCount` of threads?

My opinion: since it involves IO, most of the time will just be waiting, no processor time needed. So limiting concurrency to the number of cores make little sense.

Comment: Seems not unsensible. You don't want too many threads all working at the same time, otherwise your processor spends too much time switching between threads, and not enough time doing any actual work.

Comment: @canton7 since it involves IO, most of the time will just be waiting, no processor time needed. So limiting concurrency to the number of cores make little sense for me.

Comment: Thing is, you haven't actually shown the critical section. We don't know whether it's performing the I/O synchronously or asynchronously, and what that semaphore is actually being used for

Comment: It perform asynchronously I/O operations, sorry for that, forgot about that

Comment: So what is the semaphore actually used to protect?

Comment: It often takes a bit of trial and error to figure out what's reasonable (so making it configurable is one idea). For starters, the number of cores can vary wildly, and if (say) you're running this on a 64-core beast it is not a given that the remote service will appreciate 64 concurrent requests in short order from the same machine. Similarly, the local machine may be running other processes as well that are occupying resources; imagine this very process running twice. There is no obvious "correct" number; using the processor count at least vaguely scales with capacity.

Comment: @canton7 Number of threads, to avoid threadpool starvation I guess

Comment: I'm still none the wiser. We need to see how the semphore is actually used: when is it acquired, when is it released, and what code is run between those two points? The code in your question doesn't have anything which uses the thread pool

Comment: @canton7 I've just updated question, and pasted code from the critical section and how it use semaphore

Comment: And what does `_getRedisResultFromRedis.ExecuteAsync` do? It's starting to look like the code originally made too many network requests at once, so someone added some rate-limiting and picked the processor count only because that's a sensible choice for CPU-bound work. There's little risk of threadpool starvation if none of the calls are blocking

Comment: So if the code is non blocking I can remove semaphore, and use it without it? And why do you think processor count is sensible choice, if in I/O operations most of the time will just be waiting, no processor time needed.

Comment: I suspect it's there for a reason, so I wouldn't just remove it. Maybe the redis server doesn't like being hit with 1000 requests at once? Look through your source control history to find out who added that code, and why. You might also find a clue as to why the processor count was chosen: maybe it was a silly choice, but maybe there was a good reason. You could ask your colleagues too: maybe they'll remember, or have a good suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245025/discussion-between-svalley-dev-and-canton7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with your reasoning, since the work looks to be network requests that is limited by latency or bandwith, restricting the concurrency to the number of CPU cores make little sense.

You probably need to do some testing to find a suitable maxCount value. But ideally you should have a system that is self-adapting to the actual circumstances. I'm honestly not sure what the best design would be, but I would take a look at [dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) to see if that can provide a better way to limit concurrency. Or at least expose the value as configuration so it can be adjusted at some later time.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring the degree of parallelism with the value [`Environment.ProcessorCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount) is sensible in only one case: In case you have absolutely no clue how to configure this setting. In such a case any value will be equally random and arbitrary, so why not choose the `Environment.ProcessorCount`, which reflects somehow the capabilities of the current machine?

A similar dilemma was surfaced [while designing](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1946) the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API, that debuted on .NET 6. After evaluating the available options, the Microsoft API designers chose the `Environment.ProcessorCount` as the value for the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, when this configuration is not explicitly provided. It's ironic that the synchronous `Parallel.ForEach` API, for which the `Environment.ProcessorCount` would be an even more sensible default, it has actually -1 as the default, which means "unlimited" parallelism, or practically limited by the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) availability.